# Perl - MySQL - insertid on trigger based multi column Index not working

Tags: mysql, perl, triggers

I'm stuck with a Perl/MySQL trigger problem.

I have a mysql db with a `ProjectID` and project based `ElementID` as a multi-column index.

To be flexible with extracting or reinserting project data from multiple locations I decided to skip auto increment values and give mysql triggers a try. With the "Before create" trigger I fill up the ElementID with something like `max(ElementID)+1` and so I have a kind of a project based "auto increment" value.

Now the Perl problem part. With DBI I can get the `mysql_insertid` when I use auto increment columns.

But this does not work with my trigger based solution and using a second request to ask for a max `ElementID` for a certain `ProjectID` sounds not very elegant.

Is there another way I can get the combined index value(s) or maybe all values mysql has inserted with the last "Insert Into" command?

Comment: I am unsure there is a way to do this in MySQL (Perl - or not - does not make a difference here). Why not go with `auto_increment` to start with?

Comment: Thanks GMB. We have multiple servers with different projects on it. And from time to time it is very handy if only data from a few projects can be moved in a simple way from one server to another without leaving an auto increment hole or recreate ElementIDs on the target server. I thought about switching to noSQL, but this would be more complex on other ends of the software.

Comment: Re "*using a second request to ask for a max ElementID for a certain ProjectID sounds not very elegant.*", Sounds like a race condition, actually...

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW CREATE TRIGGER`.

Comment: What do you mean "To be flexible with extracting or reinserting project data from multiple locations"? To me this sounds like you are trying to share ElementID sequencing across projects. I'd avoid that. You probably only care that the the combination of ProjectID and ElementID are unique (because I'm guessing no elements of one project are meaningful in another). I know a lot of people get hung up in these things being sequential, but they just have to be unique values. If you wanted to track when things were created and in which order, I'd suggest a column that holds date-time info.

Comment: Hi brian. My previous version of the project was started in a hurry and so the ElementIDs was an auto increment value. So when I tried to move elements of a ProjectID to another server I had to recalc the auto increment ElementIDs on the other server. (Like I said .. hacked in a hurry.) Now it's much easier. But the main question remains. Is there a way to get the last inserted DB values in one command without creating a second query?